# How to only send specific attribute of a list in NodeJs response

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm sorry before, maybe this is a really basic question/issue but I've been stucked a while.

I've a API built use ExpressJs and Sequelize. I've successfully got the data, but I got an issue when trying to show all data as a list.
Here is my code in view to set response:

```
exports.ok = function (values, res) {
var data = {
    'status': 200,
    'values': values
};
res.json(data);
res.end();
}
```

the response showed as:

[image]

the data above show all attribute, how do I can show only name and id.
Thankyou.

Comment: Easy way: ```values: values.map(val => return { id: val.id, name: val.name });```

Comment: @Sindis it give an error syntax

Comment: values: values.map(val => ({ id: val.id, name: val.name }));

Comment: also didn't work :(

Comment: Unless you have very old version of Node.js (less than 6) it should work in the way as you described in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sindis suggested, you just need to apply `map` on the response and then select the required fields.

```
  exports.ok = function (values, res) {
      var data = {
        'status': 200,
        'values': values.map(val => return { id: val.id, name: val.name })
      };
      res.json(data);
      res.end();
    }
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: It's has been solved, I modify yours become `'values': values.map(function (value) {
            return {
                id: value.id,
                name: value.name
            }
        })`

thankyou somuch

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sequelize to get the result, you have to set attributes while querying the table. using like

```
const values = await db.Users.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    order: [
        ['id', 'ASC']
    ]
});
```

Comment: Yes I'm using sequelize, so that you mean I shoul do that in controller?

Comment: Yup. you can do while querying

Comment: yes it works, but I can do it because I show specific data based on user role. Do I right?

Comment: you can customize the object based on user role

Comment: Yes, there's is another options. Thankyou somuch :D

Answer (score 0):

> SOLVED

It work with this:

```
exports.ok = function (values, res) {
var data = {
    'status': 200,
    'values': values.map(function (value) {
        return {
            id: value.id,
            name: value.name,
            email: value.email
        }
    })
};
res.type('json');
res.send(data);
};
```